# SQL - Strange issue with SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a strange situation with a simple select by column `pqth_scan_code` from the following table:

**table pqth_**

```
Field           Type         Null   Key     Default     Extra   
pqth_id         int(11)      NO     PRI     NULL        auto_increment
pqth_scan_code  varchar(250) NO             NULL    
pqth_info       text         YES            NULL    
pqth_opk        int(11)      NO             999
```

**query 1**

This query took 12.7221 seconds to execute

```
SELECT * FROM `pqth_` WHERE pqth_scan_code = "7900722!30@3#6$EN"
```

**query 2**
This query took took 0.0003 seconds to execute

```
SELECT * FROM `pqth` WHERE `pqth_id`=27597
```

Based on data from table `pqth_` I have created the following table, where `pqthc_id` = `pqth_id` and `pqthc_scan_code`=`pqth_scan_code`

**table pqthc**

```
Field           Type         Null   Key     Default     Extra   
pqthc_id        int(11)      NO     PRI     NULL    
pqthc_scan_code tinytext     NO             NULL
```

The same query ,**query1**, on table `pqthc` took 0.0259 seconds to run

```
SELECT * FROM `pqthc` WHERE pqthc_scan_code = "7900722!30@3#6$EN"
```

If I run the following query will took 0.0971 seconds, very strange.

**query 3**

```
SELECT * FROM `pqth` WHERE pqth_id = (SELECT pqthc_id From pqthc where pqthc_scan_code = "7900722!30@3#6$EN")
```

My question is **why a SELECT by `pqth_scan_code` is slow and SELECT by `pqth_id` is fastest?** Both columns are indexed.

For testing please get the export from this [link](https://soft2u.ro/dev/user205_test.zip)

The same behavior is with MySQL and MariaDB server

Comment: From my limited knowledge, a text-based search is much *slower* in MySQL, when compared to search by numbers. I think this is what's the problem.

Comment: Have you tried going through the execution plan in SQL for all the respective queries? That might have the answers for you. And on a quick note, pqthc_scn_code is anyways varchar and with no index on it, it has to take time in fetching data. And yes, number of columns retrieved by the engine in memory make difference in I/O operations and hence final time taken. You will see that in the execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `pqth_` WHERE pqth_scan_code = "7900722!30@3#6$EN"
```

needs `INDEX(pqth_scan_code)`.  Period.  End of discussion.

```
SELECT * FROM `pqth` WHERE `pqth_id`=27597
```

has a useful index, since a `PRIMARY KEY` is an index (and it is unique).

```
SELECT * FROM `pqthc` WHERE pqthc_scan_code = "7900722!30@3#6$EN"
```

also needs `INDEX(pqthc_scan_code)`.  But it may have been faster because (1) the table is smaller, or (2) you ran the query before, thereby caching what was needed in RAM.

Please don't prefix column names with the table name.
Please don't have table names so close to each other that they are hard to distinguish.  (`pqth` and `pqthc`)

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  `pqth`
    WHERE  pqth_id = 
      ( SELECT  pqthc_id
            From  pqthc
            where  pqthc_scan_code = "7900722!30@3#6$EN"
      )
```

The construct `IN ( SELECT ... )` is not efficient.

It is rare to have two table with the same `PRIMARY KEY`; are you sure you meant that?

Use a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT  a.*
    FROM  `pqth` AS a
    JOIN  pqthc AS c ON a.id = c.id
    where  c.scan_code = "7900722!30@3#6$EN"
```

If that is 'correct', then I recommend this 'covering' index:

```
INDEX(scan_code, id)
```

instead of the shorter `INDEX(scan_code)` I previously recommended.

[More on indexing](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: Thank you for good answer. Table pqthc is only for testing the query `SELECT  a.*
    FROM  `pqth` AS a
    JOIN  pqthc AS c ON a.id = c.id
    where  c.scan_code = "7900722!30@3#6$EN" ` . Also an join query if more bad. Adding index on collumn `scan_code` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to understand the concept of primary key and indexes and how they help in searching, 
reference docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: I know the concept, but why query1 takes more time than query 2. The number of columns from table has a such big impact on the query?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `pqthc_scan_code` has no index/key and `pqthc_id` does, keys help making searches faster.

Another difference is that `pqthc_id` is an integer where as `pqthc_scan_code` is a string. comparing integers is a lot more efficient than comparing strings.

You should avoid having to search on strings in really large tables.

You could add a index/key to `pqthc_scan_code` but i don't know how much it will help.

You can use EXPLAIN in fronto of your query to try and figure out what takes so long [More info on `EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)

Comment: but same query,query 1 and query 2, on the both table has different execution time,

Comment: the other table has less rows i'm assuming? it's a bit confusing because you have a tabled called 'pqth', 'pqth_' and 'pqhtc' ?

Comment: Other tables has more rows and more columns. The table `pqth_` is a 1:1 copy of `pqth` table and is used for testing. Also I have another table with a column containing `scan_code` more big than `pqth` and searching by a`scan_code` is more faster.

Comment: It's hard to tell without being able to try myself, you could add both table with inserte date in sql fiddle and post that here. Or try using EXPLAIN in front of your query and see what takes so much time